# Pattern matching based on the function signature

Tags: f#, functional-programming, statsd

In F# can you pattern match on a function signature. I want to decorate a number of functions with a function that measures the execution of the function and calls out to statsd. The current function I have is:

```
let WrapFunctionWithPrefix(metrics:Metric.Client.IRecorder, functionToWrap, prefix) =
    let metricsIdentifier = (sprintf "%s.%s" prefix Environment.MachineName)
    using (metrics.StartTimer(metricsIdentifier)) ( fun metrics -> functionToWrap)
```

As you can see above, the prefix will vary, and in our application this will vary per function definition. So rather than having to pass in the measure prefix every time I want to do something like the following:

```
let WrapFunction metrics afunc = 
    match afunc with
    | :? (int -> int) -> WrapFunctionWithPrefix(metrics, afunc, "My function 1")
    | :? (string -> string) -> WrapFunctionWithPrefix(metrics, afunc, "My function 2")
    | _ -> failwith "Unknown function def"
```

Is there any way of pattern matching based on the function signature in F#?

Any help appreciated.

Billy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would it be possible to declare the cases as a DU?

```
type MyFunctions =
| Intish of int -> int
| Stringish of string -> string
```

Comment: Cheers, went down this route and worked. Slightly more elegant!

Answer (score 3):

```
let WrapFunction metrics afunc = 
    match box afunc with
    | :? (int -> int) -> WrapFunctionWithPrefix(metrics, afunc, "My function 1")
    | :? (string -> string) -> WrapFunctionWithPrefix(metrics, afunc, "My function 2")
    | _ -> failwith "Unknown function def"
```

will work for your pattern match. You normally end up having to `box` unknown types before trying to cast them, as :? doesn't like being used on value types.

I'm not totally sure how your using statement will interact with the function you return though. I think it will dispose metrics and return the function immediately, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Also note that you get no type safety at all on your ``afunc`` parameter. If someone wants to pass in something that isn't a function, the compiler won't stop them.