# What data structure should I use to hold a collection of functions in F#

Tags: f#

Some features of the data structure worth mentioning:
1. The functions will NOT all have the same signatures (my main issue)
2. The data structure does not have to be immutable

I'm comfortable with all the main vanilla data structures, my concern is around what "generalized type" is the best umbrella type to represent a function in such a collection of functions. In particular, is their anything better than just boxing them as obj / System.Object?

When the function is being "packed" into the data structure I will know it's signature. This can be stored in some way and linked to this function such that it can be used to "unpack" the function into the correct form when it is needed.

I am assuming that I can create function signature types and store them in a collection of their own - perhaps this is a bad assumption though? In other words:

```
let f1: float-> float
let f2: string->bool->float
```

Can the `typeof(f1)` and `typeof(f2)` be stored in the same data structure. I would think that since they are both of type `Type` this should be possible

In reply to the comment below by @ildjarn: The expected signatures could be any 1-5 input parameter combinations of the usual suspects like float, string, bool, date and with the result parameter varying equally over float | string | bool.

Taking the above into account, how best can the functions be stored for later retrieval and application (partial or full) and or composition with other functions.

## EDIT

The simplest approach I can come up with is the following:

```
let f1 x = exp x
let t1 = f1.GetType()
let o1 = box f1 // alternate syntax
let f11 = o1 :?> t1 // ?? FAILS HERE!!!!!
f11 3.0
```

But I don't know how to downcast from the object back to the function type I had prior to boxing.

Comment: Is the set of signatures unbounded? If so, what good is the collection? I.e., how would you actually use/invoke any of the functions contained?

Comment: @ildjarn That is a good point. The set is finite, though there are quite a few permutations of signature. I should probably add the unwrapping and invoking part to the question.

Comment: One more piece of information that we need to answer this is - how do you want to call the functions? Do you have all parameters available and the functions will just use some of them? Do you only call some of the functions (when you have parameters they need)? Or is there some other strategy? Also, what are you going to do with the result (of a type you do not know...)?

Comment: @TomasPetricek I will reword the question to answer the above

Comment: If there *is* a limit to the inputs, maybe you could hold them as a collection of discriminated unions.

Comment: @TomasPetricek reworded. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: @Sam - this helps a bit - and I guess you could use discriminated union if there is limited number of cases, but if you can clarify how you want to use the collection of functions, that would help more - e.g. do you want to call all functions that take `string` and `bool` at some point? Or do you have some values that you can convert to the required input types?

Comment: @TomasPetricek Overall what I am trying to do is building/composing a single function from a whole lot of smaller parts. My function will take in a RPN stack of input related to a math/logic expression it is trying to build and then will build the required function/expression via function composition and partial application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pattern matching based on the function signature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29627950/pattern-matching-based-on-the-function-signature)

Answer (score 2):

Build yourself a discriminated union (DU) for the different sigs:

```
type Function<'a, 'b, 'c, 'd> =
| Unary of ('a -> 'd)
| Binary of ('a -> 'b -> 'd)
| Ternary of ('a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd)
```

then make say `Function<'a, 'b, 'c, 'd> list` to hold your functions. This should work well enough, so long as the signatures are not too heterogeneous. Because you still require to have at most as many different kinds of signatures as you have cases in your DU.

A fully working example might look like this:

```
open System

type Operator = 
| Parse of (string -> int)
| Unary of (int -> int)
| Binary of (int -> int -> int)
| Print of (int -> unit)

type Data =
| Int of int
| String of string

type StackContent =
| Data of Data
| Operator of Operator

let input = [
    Data (String "3")
    Operator (Parse Int32.Parse)
    Data (String "5")
    Operator (Parse Int32.Parse)
    Operator (Binary (+))
    Operator (Unary (~-))
    Operator (Print (printfn "%d"))]

let eval input =
    let rec eval = function
        | Data d :: inputTail, stack -> eval (inputTail, d::stack)
        | Operator (Parse parse) :: inputTail, String s :: stackTail -> eval (inputTail, Int (parse s) :: stackTail)
        | Operator (Binary (++)) :: inputTail, Int l :: Int r :: stackTail -> eval (inputTail, Int (l ++ r) :: stackTail)
        | Operator (Unary (!)) :: inputTail, Int i :: stackTail -> eval (inputTail, Int !i :: stackTail)
        | Operator (Print print) :: inputTail, Int i :: stackTail ->
            print i
            eval (inputTail, stackTail)
        | [], [] -> ()
        | input, stack -> failwithf "the following thing is not properly typed\nInput: %A\Stack: %A" input stack
    eval (input,[])

eval input
```

Comment: Thank u for the interest in my Q. The problem (for me) is that I can't store two Unary function types *with different signatures* in the same collection because once the generic parameters have been inferred, they have been set.

Comment: Sure you can, just make two different cases with two different signatures. Loot at `Parse`, `Print` and `Unary`

Comment: Surely their is a way to get a boxed function out of an object if you knew the type signature at the time of boxing? It's a different direction than you or Tomas have taken but it seems like the simplest approach to me

Comment: Well, you can make an unsafe dynamic downcast `:?>`

Comment: let f2 (s:string) = s.Length 
let wf1 = Unary(exp)
let wf2 = Unary(f2)
let wf3 = Binary((+))
let lst = [wf1; wf2; wf3]
//fails in the list for wf2

Comment: the unsafe downcast didn't work - I'm going to put that code into the main body of the question now.

Comment: I see your problem with `exp : float -> float` vs `f2 : string -> int`. The point is, you would, in this approach, need two cases. Say `UnaryFloatToFloat` and `UnaryStringToInt`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76984/discussion-between-sam-and-daniel-fabian).

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the context in which you are doing this, but you'll need to wrap the functions and the arguments in some way. You could box them and work with `obj` values (and then use reflection), you could wrap them in discriminated unions and you could likely do other things.

The discriminated union approach is probably the easiest. You could have a DU for different kinds of values that you support:

```
type Value =
  | Int of int
  | String of string
```

A function then takes a list of values and produces a value (you can make it option, because the function might fail if it gets incorrect arguments):

```
type Function = Value list -> Value option
```

To define your collection of functions, you can create a list. Each function will pattern match on the input to make sure it is getting the expected values:

```
let functions = 
  [ ( function 
      | [ Int n; String t ] -> 
          Some(String(sprintf "The %s is %d" t n))
      | _ -> None) ]
```

Then you can create a list of arguments and call the function:

```
let arguments = [ Int 42; String "Answer" ]    
functions.[0] arguments
```

This is really just one of multiple options, but it is the simplest one to start from. The disadvantage is that you need to explicitly unwrap the parameters and wrap the results in `Value` - but you could probably later automate that using some reflection or type casting.

Comment: Thanks. If you were to box the functions as objects, how would you later unbox them with reflection (as you mention above)?